# Include header files from another directory using makefile (C code)

Tags: c, makefile

I have a directory structure like:

- Current directory: within it there are two sub-directories (Directory1 and Directory2).
  -Directory1: has a sub-directory with header files(.h) and .c files which are the implemnetations of the .h files in the sub-directory. (.c Files are not within sub-directory but Directory1)
  -Directory2: has .c files and Makefile.

My Makefile is:

```
CC = gcc
OBJS = latency.o utils.o 
out: $(OBJS)
HEADER = ../Directory1/include/
CFLAGS = -c -Wall -Iinclude

out: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o out $(OBJS)

latency.o: latency.c include/utils.h $(HEADER)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    
utils.o: utils.c include/utils.h $(HEADER)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

run:
    ./out
```

But i got :

```
gcc -c -Wall -Iinclude utils.c -o utils.o
gcc -o out latency.o utils.o 
/usr/bin/ld: latency.o: in function `main':
latency.c:(.text+0x1b4): undefined reference to 'function_name'
/usr/bin/ld: latency.c:(.text+0x1bc): undefined reference to 'function_name' 
/usr/bin/ld: utils.o: in function `get_timing':
utils.c:(.text+0x20c): undefined reference to `function_name'
```

What mistakes have i made ?

Comment: Did you define `function_name`? This looks like more of a C problem than a Makefile problem. The build commands look sensible (assuming neither `latency.c` nor `utils.c` have changed since you last built them). Certainly (or most likely) this is not a problem with headers; it's a link problem.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWingsYes, i defined it in .h file in /Directory1/include/header.h

Comment: You put declarations in headers. Where did you _define_ it? We're going to need a [mcve] for your code.

Comment: @Amessihel i am not sure i got all that

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings i'm sorry,  i defined it in .c file within Directory1

Comment: @Nick _Which_ .c file?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I modified the question so i hope it is more clear.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Directory1 has a sub-directory with .h files and .c files (.c files are not in the sub-directory but in the Directory1) and they are the implementations of the .h file. Directory2 contains .c files should include .h files of the Directory1.

Comment: You still haven't told me what file contains the definition of `function_name`. Where did you define `function_name`? What is the name of the file? The full name, not just its extension.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings A .c file within Directory1. The file Called memory.c

Comment: Right, so the function `function_name` is defined in `memory.c`. But you did not mention `memory.c` anywhere in your Makefile. Your Makefile has no idea that `memory.c` exists. It does not compile `memory.c`, and it does not link `memory.o`. So, the definition for `function_name` does not exist in your program. And that is what your linker is telling you. Why don't you have steps for `memory.o` in your `Makefile`?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings ok, i got it. but how can i link memory.c file in the makefile?

Comment: In the exact same way that you compiled and linked your other source files, `latency.c` and `utils.c`...

Comment: Your project layout is a bit strange, but you could write `../Directory2/memory.c` and `../Directory2/memory.o` everywhere you need to name the files